# Access denied for a DLL when using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

I deployed an MVC4 application on IIS 8.5 with full permissions to folders and temp folders, I have a DLL called `business.dll` that access a WCF service on another server. When I have forms authentication every thing works fine, but when I have windows authentication it gives me access denied to the `business.dll`.

I tried to :

- exclude mcafee service on temp folder;
- run with all permission the application pool and the website;
- change temp folder.

but i did not succeed ,below is stack trace:

> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'BuisnessModel,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. Access is denied.]    RoyalFleet.MvcApplication..ctor()
>   +0    ASP.global_asax..ctor() in c:\Users\rfadmin\desktop\temp\test\97712bb4\cadef3a5\App_global.asax.qpfh6khy.0.cs:0
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1138
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +124    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +18
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[]
>   args) +60
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +260
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9931880 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

any help please?

Comment: This is difficult to answer without more details.  Perhaps including the error message with a stack trace will help to clarify.

Comment: i added the stack trace 10x bro